# Why isn't my reset function stopping?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, return, reset

My reset button continues to clear the canvas and empty the chat box. Shouldn't the return statement end the function?

Main.js

```
var reset = function() {
    context.clearRect(0,0, canvas[0].width, canvas[0].height); 
    context.beginPath();
    $('#guesses').children().empty();
    socket.emit('reset', reset);
    return;
};


$('#reset').on("click", reset);

socket.on('reset', reset);
```

Server.js

```
socket.on('reset', function(){
   socket.broadcast.emit('reset');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of your `reset` function, you're emitting a `reset` event.

```
socket.emit('reset', reset);
```

You've also setup a handler for when the `reset` event is emitted.

```
socket.on('reset', reset);
```

So every time you call `reset`, you're emitting an event which ends up calling `reset` again.

Comment: Thanks I got it, I did: `$('#reset').on("click", function(){
        socket.emit('reset');
        reset();
    });` and removed the emit from the reset function.

Comment: @TedTzuridis Glad I could help!